# Как открыть два браузера одновременно

Tags: браузер

У меня установлено два браузера, а именно: Mozilla Firefox и Opera. Иногда мне нужно воспользоваться двумя браузерами одновременно(очень нужно для форумов), но, когда я пытаюсь открыть оперу, то мозила открывает мне просто новую вкладку. Раньше такого не было, опера открывалась спокойно. Что случилось? (Мозила - браузер по умолчанию).

Comment: Вы не указали достаточно данных - ОС, проверяли ли антивирусом.
Но думаю, это вопрос на биткод.

Comment: > Иногда мне нужно воспользоваться двумя браузерами одновременно(очень нужно для форумов)

не в Ольгино случайно работаете?

Comment: Простите, не знаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Так что, точно нет.

Comment: Нетбук недавно с ремонта, где, как мне сказали, его почистили от всех вирусов. Windows 7. Что это "биткод"?

Comment: DreamChild, спасибо, напишу туда. Просто уже не знаю, куда обратиться.